# Medir uso del disco o cpu en c++

Tags: c++, mysql-workbench

¿Hay alguna forma o alguna función de c++ para medir el uso del disco duro y de la cpu?

Estoy en un sistema Linux,y estoy haciendo un script que realiza unas operaciones sobre una base de datos, me gustaría medir el uso del disco duro y de la memoria por parte de estas operaciones.

Comment: debes agregar un ejemplo minimo de lo que llevas o puedes utilizar los comandos internos del so. como `free -m` o `df -h`

Answer (score 2):

> ¿Hay alguna forma o alguna función de c++ para medir el uso del disco duro y de la cpu?

No. Eso es dependiente de sistema operativo, no de lenguaje de programación.

Lo que puedes hacer es leer el "archivo" [`proc/stat`](http://www.linuxhowtos.org/System/procstat.htm) e interpretar el contenido.